# Excel Error: Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml part

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving the error stated in the the title when re-opening a macro-enabled excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has about 8 tabs and they all formatted almost exactly the same. My macro moves rows to different sheets based on a data validation cell value in the last column. There is only one line of code that sorts anything, and it is sorting Sheet 6, not sheet 5.

```
Worksheets("Follow-Ups").Range("A:AD").Sort Key1:=Range("AC2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

I have looked over some of the other similar questions on StackOverflow about this error, but it doesn't seem that there has been any definitive reason stated for why this happens.

I have messed around with some things within my VBA code but the error always seems to return. I am in the process of copying my data over to a brand new workbook and re-doing the code. I will also be saving it as a Binary excel file instead of macro enabled.

Has anyone else encountered this error and what are some other possible solutions I can try to prevent this error from happening again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be due to unqualified ranges.

> `Worksheets("Follow-Ups").Range("A:AD").Sort Key1:=Range("AC2"), ...`
>
> ```
>                                                   ^^^^^^
> ```

Suppose that at the moment of running this statement, the currently active worksheet is not "Follow-Ups", but another one (i.e. `Sheet5`). You would be sorting a range from "Follow-Ups" using a key range that belongs to another worksheet (the currently active one). This leads to a runtime error.

Qualifying the range is mandatory:

```
Worksheets("Follow-Ups").Range("A:AD").Sort Key1:=Worksheets("Follow-Ups").Range("AC2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

You can simplify it using a `With` clause:

```
With Worksheets("Follow-Ups")
    .Range("A:AD").Sort Key1:=.Range("AC2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

The error displayed by VBA is probably due to that `Sheet5` was the active sheet, and surely it could not use its range "AC2" as key.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Thank you! Though if I remember correctly it always seemed to be a sheet 5 error, but the workbook might always open up to sheet5.

Comment: @gluc7 Always use qualified ranges. Unqualified ones lead to unexpected errors and sometimes difficult to explain. I hope this helped.

Comment: I have fixed the line in my code now and tested multiple different scenarios that led to the error previously and so far it looks like this change has worked. Thanks again!